# Use php to get string with quotations or apostrophe from database, use json_encode, and then try to parse the JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, react-native

I have a table full of strings in a database, about a sentence long each. Some have quotation marks in them or apostrophes. I run a fetch in React-native, which runs a php file. This php file gets a random item from the table and echos it so the javascript can parse the JSON string and do things with it. If the string has quotation marks or apostrophe(s), the app crashes with "JSON parse error: unexpected EOF". I have tried addslashes() and I have even tried using the php function str_replace() to replace quotations and apostrophes with obscure characters. Either way, I still get the crash and the same error message. Here is part of the code here:

```php
$get_fate = "SELECT * FROM $fates ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$run_fate = mysqli_query($con, $get_fate);
$num_fates = mysqli_num_rows($run_fate);
if ($num_fates == 1) {
    $row_fate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_fate);
    $fate = $row_fate['fate'];

    $msg = addslashes($fate);
    $msg_json = json_encode($msg);
    echo $msg_json;
} else ...
```

And the javascript side:

```js
getFate = async () => {
    let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');

    fetch('fetch address goes here', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application.json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: user
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({fate: responseJson});
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Here is an image of the crash:

[image]

And if it means anything, I was sent a big word file of all these "fates". I used fates.splitlines() in python to separate them all into separate strings and put them into an array, which I looped through in php and inserted into the database. I then noticed there was some kind of klingon looking text where quotes and apostrophes should be, so I "fixed" that with the following SQL queries:

```js
UPDATE choose_your_fate SET fate = REPLACE(fate, 'â€œ', '“');
UPDATE choose_your_fate SET fate = REPLACE(fate, 'â€', '”');
UPDATE choose_your_fate SET fate = REPLACE(fate, 'â€™', '’');
UPDATE choose_your_fate SET fate = REPLACE(fate, 'â€˜', '‘');
```

Comment: You really don't need to use `addslashes()`. Can you give some examples of the strings in your DB?

Comment: Some examples: You talk like Porky the Pig between the hours of 7am and 6pm.
(doesn't crash the app)
Whenever the name “Benjamin” is spoken around you in a 50 yard radius, you instantly lay an egg of various sizes.
(crashes the app because of the quotation marks around Benjamin)
Every morning when you wake up there is a dead, rotting emperor penguin in your bed.
(doesn't crash the app)
Your name is “Pugh Pugh” and you have to refer to yourself in third person.
(crashes the app because of the quotation marks around Pugh Pugh); So uhh, this is for a game someone is making...

Comment: Could you post some screenshots from Postman or something similar of the responses? And again, you don't need `addslashes()`

Comment: FYI, your `Content-type` request header value is wrong (should be `application/json`). That's unlikely the problem though

Comment: Removed addshlashes(). It still crashed on this string: Any time you see, read, or hear “Magic Johnson,” your day starts over. (crashed because of the quotes around Magic Johnson). And I'm not sure what Postman is? I added an image of the crash screen to the original post.

Comment: What do you have in `$fate` variable?

Comment: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is a tool for testing APIs. If you have `curl` already, try `curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"email":"some@email.address"}' "http://your.host/your/php/script.php"`. Please show the result in your question exactly how it appears

Comment: $fate variable is just the name of the table in the database. I'm downloading postman now.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to add a header to your PHP of Content Type (application/json).

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Next, it's probably your JSON is ill-formed. Instead of using

```
response.json()
```

trying using

```
response.text()
```

this should return the String from the server.

It could be that you have an error message in your PHP which is coming back in the response, or illformed JSON.

As a general point of refactor. Consider using try catches in your code, so you don't crash the app when you encounter a non-show stopper like this.

Like:

```
getFate = async () => {
    let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');

    fetch('fetch address goes here', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application.json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: user
        })
    }).then((response) => response.text())
    .then((responseTxt) => {
        //Console log out the response, so you can see the response
        console.log(responseTxt);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

The OP has stated the response from the server is incorrect.

It seems special characters are breaking your response. Can you use the QUOTE function in MySQL?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_quote

Comment: So now the app doesn't crash, but the card comes up blank if there are quotes in the string. Does this mean it is likely something wrong in the php?

Comment: Took away json_encode() so I just echo the $fate. Now it will show up on the app without crashing, but quotes and apostrophes show as a black diamond with a question mark in it.

Comment: I've added in the updated code, just log out the (or breakpoint) the line your interested in. Go to your console and see what the response is outputted as. You don't want to change the json_encode echo within the PHP.

Comment: I brought back the json_encode. Added the console.log(responseTxt); so the fates will show in the console. But ones with quotes or apostrophes don't show at all, in the console or on the app.

Comment: I was also able to run the php file itself so it echoes the fates on the browser. They show up until I get one with quotes or apostrophes, and then it is blank.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you show me an example of a response from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Added all the fates to the database by manually typing to insert them; it didn't like them being copy pasted from a word document. When I take them from the database, it is necessary to use the addslashes(); function so the text shows on the app screen.